# Calculating Formula

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to achieve a program that takes in an equation from the user (in 1 line) and outputs the result. So far I have I'm using indexof to find the + sign, and then Im trying to find the value of the number to the left and right of the + sign  -

```
            string input = "5+4+6";
            while (input.Contains('+'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input.IndexOf("+"));

                string position1 = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("+"));
                int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(position1);

                String position2 = input.Substring(2, input.IndexOf("+"));
                int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(position2);

                int sum = (number1 + number2);
```

The problem with my code is that I am stating the number to the left and converting it to a int whereas in real life the numbers in the equation will be unkown , can be 2+4, or 3+5+6+4, for simplicity for now Im trying to do + and - , then / and *.

Could anyone suggest an improvement on the code or any help?
I know there are other ways to calculate formula such as ncalc, but I would like to stick to this approach.

Thank you

Comment: why not use the Split function and then you could add up the values in the string array using the proper Convert.ToInt32 method along with that..

Comment: That would work if you're performing only one type of operation in the input...only adding, or only subtracting...etc. If you wanted to support Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division all in the same input, it will not be as straightforward as that.

Comment: With .Split() you lose what the actual operator was.  If it's always '+' that works fine.

Comment: @EricJ. If you split(" x " ) you know you will have to " x " all result. Of coure you will have to add some recursion for work with all operators.

Comment: @EricJ. I disagree since in the code the op is doing the sum = number1 + number2 so if he know's what operation he's performing then he could determine if it's , -, %, *` etc...

Answer (score 3):

From what you've given, if this is the expected `string` input, you could do something like this:

```
string input = "5+4+6";
int result = 0;
while (input.Contains('+'))
{
    var numbers = input.Split('+');

    foreach(var num in numbers)
    {
        result += Convert.ToInt32(num);
    }
}
```

Something similar to this should work, and you can substitute the `+` for any of the operators.

Answer (score 2):

If the only operator you need to worry about is +, you can just use string.Split() to create an array of strings, then convert them to integers and sum them up.  You can even further simplify some of that with Linq.

```
string[] numbers = input.Split('+');
int sum = input.Select(n => int.Parse(n)).Sum();
```

You could even put that together into one statement

```
int sum = input.Split('+').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).Sum();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about.. since he only stated wanting to add.. then of course following your example one could make an extension method based on a token several ways to skin this cat.. good example btw

Comment: I will be looking to do multiply and divide, will the code be very different?

Comment: Yes.  If that's the case, look at The Godfather's answer about the Shunting-yard algorithm.  You can't just loop through the characters because of the order of operation rules (usually all * and / are processed before + and -), e.g. 1+2*3 = 1+6 = 7.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for study purposes and for this particular case you can use your approach with "manual" parsing.

But for real life if you you want to parse formulas, I recommend you to read about [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It's the way how you can parse any formulas without any limits for operations (you can implement this for "+" and then add "-", "*", "/" and even "sin", "cos" operations easily).

Answer (score 0):

To handle addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division as well as taking order of operations into account...I would look up the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). This will take the input expression which is given as infix notation and convert it to reverse-Polish notation. There are plenty of .NET implementations of the Shunting-Yard Algorithm that you can look at.

As everyone else has said, if the input only contains one operation type, say addition, then you can use `.Split('+')` and then parse out each integer and add them together.

Answer (score 0):

I use same precedence as Excel. Work for `+ - * /` 
 [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/30qQeP)

This work only with integer numbers in the formula. Even when return double to store the division.
If you want accept double in the formula try `double.Parse` instead of `int.Parse`

> `=1+2*3/4-5+6*7/8-9` will get -6.75. 
>   First operations are 3/4 and 7/8 
>   then 2 * 0.75 and 6 * 0.875
>   then 1.5 - 5  and 5.25 - 9
>   finally 1 + (-3.5) + (-3.75)

`=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9` is 45 
`=1-2-3-4` is -8 
`=1*2*3*4`  is 24 
`=1/2/3/4` is 0.416667

```
public static void Main()
{
    int n;
    bool isNumeric;
    string input = "1+2*3/4-5+6*7/8-9";
    string[] addSplit = input.Split('+');
    double addTotal = 0;
    foreach (string addCode in addSplit)
    {
        isNumeric = int.TryParse(addCode, out n);
        if (isNumeric)
        {
            addTotal += n;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] addMinus = addCode.Split('-');
            double minusTotal = 0;
            bool firstMinus = true;
            foreach (string minusCode in addMinus)
            {
                isNumeric = int.TryParse(minusCode, out n);
                if (isNumeric)
                {
                    if (firstMinus) { 
                        minusTotal = n;
                        firstMinus = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        minusTotal -= n;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] multySplit = minusCode.Split('*');
                    double multyTotal = 1;
                    foreach (string multyCode in multySplit)
                    {
                        isNumeric = int.TryParse(multyCode, out n);
                        if (isNumeric)
                        {
                            multyTotal *= n;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string[] divSplit = multyCode.Split('/');                               
                            int.TryParse(divSplit[0], out n);                               
                            double divTotal = n;    

                            for( int i = 1; i < divSplit.Length ; i++ ) {   
                                int.TryParse(divSplit[i], out n);
                                divTotal /= n;
                            }
                            multyTotal *= divTotal;                         
                        }
                    }
                    if (firstMinus) { 
                        minusTotal = multyTotal;
                        firstMinus = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        minusTotal -= multyTotal;
                    }   
                }
            }
            addTotal += minusTotal;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("addTotal: " + addTotal);
}
```